# Comparison function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data that tracks each agents phone statuses each day.

I am trying to track if an employee has two specific events happen on the same day within 15 minutes of each other.

```
EmployeeName    EventName   StatusTime  Date  T/F
Bob             X            8:30       5/15   
Bob             Y            8:46       5/15   F
Adam            X            8:30       5/15   
Adam            Y            8:44       5/15   T
```

I have tried to understand how to do this, and I am completely lost at this point. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$D$1:D2,D2)=1,"",COUNTIFS($A$1:A2,A2,$D$1:D2,D2,$C$1:C2,">="&C2 - TIME(0,15,0),$C$1:C2,"<="&C2 +TIME(0,15,0))>1)
```

[image]